# Use other column than x data for ggbarplot as x labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataframe of which I want to make a barplot. An example dataset:

```
    Class      Cell_name      Sub_cluster   Tissue  Count
    Astrocyte  Astrocyte 1        CB_1-1       CB     8
    Astrocyte  Astrocyte 1        FC_1-1       FC     4
    Astrocyte  Astrocyte 2        CB_1-2       CB     1
    Astrocyte  Astrocyte 3        CB_1-3       CB    20
    Astrocyte  Astrocyte 3        FC_1-3       FC     6
```

I want to make a barplot with ggplot of this. I want the bars being based on the sub_clusters, meaning in this case I would have a plot with 5 bars. However, on the x-axis I would like to have the labels of the cell names instead of the ones from the subclusters. So, for the cell name Astrocyte 1 I want to have two separate bars for each sub cluster, both with the name Astrocyte 1. 
I've come a little bit further with some help (see the comments) and this is the code I have now, with classes being a factor of all unique cell classes I have.

```
for (i in classes){
  ggbarplot(data[which(grepl(i,data$Class)),], 
            x='Sub_cluster', y='Count',
            sort.val='asc', color='Tissue', alpha=0.5) +  
    labs(title=paste('Expression of DMD in the mouse brain of class',i), 
         x='Cell type', y='UMI counts') + 
 scale_x_discrete(labels=data[which(grepl(i,data$Class)),'Cell_name']) +
        theme_classic() + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))

      ggsave(paste(path_plotstorage,'dropviz_celltypes_norm',i,'.pdf',sep=''))
    }
```

Here `scale_x_discrete(labels=data[which(grepl(i,data$Class)),'Cell_name'])` is the line that gives me the names. However, while they are grouped as they should be per tissue, they don't have the ascending order the bars have, but an alphabetical order.

I've also added the plot I got using the whole dataset, which might be helpful.

[image: Total bar plot[1]]

For example: In this plot I would like to have **CB_8-2, CB_7-1, CB_8-1**, *ENT 7-2, ENT 7-1* changed to **Astrocyte 8-2, Astrocyte 7-1, Astrocyte 8-1**, *Astrocyte 7-2, Astrocyte 7-1*. However, with the code I have now they are changed to **Astrocyte 7-1, Astrocyte 8-1, Astrocyte 8-2**, *Astrocyte 7-1, Astrocyte 7-2* .

(I don't need the bold/italic fond, that is just to indicate which cell names correspond to which sub clusters)

Comment: So, cell name `Astrocyte 1` has at least two sub clusters. Do you want (a) separate bars for each subcluster, each labeled `Astrocyte 1`, (b) separate bars for each subcluster, but they are next to each other and there is a single `Astrocyte 1` label, (c) something else?

Comment: And, if the case is (a) or (b), how do you want the order of the bars on the x-axis determined? And do you want there to be any way to determine the subcluster? Or indicate the differences between multiple bars with the same/shared label?

Comment: Also, please expand on why you "cannot simply use" `scale_x_discrete(labels=data$Cell_name)`---I don't understand how the size of your data makes that not work. Seems like if you used the same subset of data something along those lines would work well... `labels = data[which(grepl(i,data$Class)), "Cell_name"]`, though you may need to adjust the ordering to match the order of the x-axis variable.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I would like to have case a, so separate bars for each subluster with the same label. The difference between two bars would be in this case be indicated by the color, since they both come from a different kind of tissue (one from the CB, the other one from the FC). It would be nice to have the order as I have now, so kind of grouped per tissue. Another useful option would be to have them grouped per cell name, but still keeping the colors based on the tissue. I'm trying your option now!

Comment: What if you did `ggplot(data[which(grepl(i,data$Class)),], aes(x = Cell_name, y = Count, fill = Tissue)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`. It's option (b), but it's quite simple. You may want to modify to `position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")` instead of just `position = 'dodge'`

Comment: It kind of works. The names are there and they are grouped per tissue as they should be, only they aren't in the ascending order but are alphabetically ordered. Is it possible to fix this or should I just let go of wanting to have the ascending order? Sorry this was about your earlier fix, my internet is a bit slow

Comment: It's difficult (but possible) to get the ascending order within Cell_name using the `position_dodge` method. Unfortunately I don't have more time to work on this now, but others will help. I would recommend editing some of the details we've worked out in comments into the question itself so that new people reading the question don't need to also read the comments to get all the info. Specifically, the desire to have the bars in ascending `Count` order within each `cell_name` grouping is important. Also the details of why your `scale_x_discrete` attempt wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: For what you are looking for, probably the `scale_x_discrete` method is easiest, you just need to get the right subset of your data and the right order for those labels.

Comment: Okay I'll edit my question. Thank you very much for all the help!